# How to prove $\left(\!\!\binom{n}k\!\!\right)=\left(\!\!\binom{k+1}{n-1}\!\!\right)$ (multichoose) algebraically?

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

How to prove algebraically that

$$\left(\!\!\binom{n}k\!\!\right)=\left(\!\!\binom{k+1}{n-1}\!\!\right)$$

I am having a good amount of trouble understanding the algebraic side of problems like these. I have the combinatorial side down, but for some reason, I really struggle with the breakdown of each side of the proof and how the canceling works.

Comment: You mean $${n\choose k}={k+1\choose n-1}$$?

Comment: No. That would just be "choose". This problem involves "multichoose", which is with two parentheses on each side of the equal sign, which I guess also defines as number of multisets with cardinality k whose elements belong to an n-element set (or cardinality n-1 whose elements belong to an k+1-element set for the right side).

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram mathworld says](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html)$$\left({n\choose k}\right)={n+k-1\choose k}$$

This  means your claim that $$\left({n\choose k}\right)=\left({k+1\choose n-1}\right)\\\implies {n+k-1\choose k}={k+1+n-1-1\choose n-1}$$

is **Absolutely Trival**!

Comment: Yeah that's what I had, but for some reason, I thought it could simplify much further. What about in a problem such as

Comment: (n choose k) * (k choose m) = (n choose m) * (n-m choose k-m)? I had this as a homework problem last week and was completely puzzled on how to approach it?

Comment: @knxwledge Go from the basics. use the formula Wolfram gave. It will get done.

Comment: @knxwledge: The identity in your comment has a straightforward combinatorial proof, and the algebraic proof is just a matter of writing out the quotients of products of factorials.

Comment: @knxwledge Don't inculcate the habit (as done by many users here) of leaving answers un accepted. Check the tick mark in the answer if it satisfied you. If not , I will clear your doubts.